# how to save tensor as a image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to save tensor as a image in specific folder. I am using tf.write() but I don't know where it save the image. Kindly tell me the way to save it as jpeg image

```
path = "C:/Users/waqas/Desktop/0"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
    img = flip_images(file)
    img2 = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.uint8,saturate=True)
    enc = tf.image.encode_png(img2)
    file_name = tf.constant(file)
    files = tf.write_file(file_name, enc)
```

Comment: Here you are overwriting each original image with the new one. BTW, what do you mean by `way to save it as jpeg image`. Png to jpeg ?

Comment: Flip_image returns a image. I want simple save that image as a jpeg.

Comment: what's the format of the image? Is it png or jpeg?

Comment: In any format. No problem

Comment: Here is code of flip images which returns tf_img           
    `def flip_images(X_imgs):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
    tf_img = tf.image.flip_left_right(X)
    return tf_img`

Comment: Actual image which I read is in jpg format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from PIL import Image

path = "D:\\data\\"
new_path = "D:\\new_folder\\"

filenames = os.listdir(path)
filenames = [path+images for images in filenames]
no_of_files = len(filenames)

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=no_of_files)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key,value = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value)
reshaped_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners()

    for i in range(no_of_files):
        img = sess.run(reshaped_image)
        img = Image.fromarray(img)
        img.save(os.path.join(new_path+str(i)+".jpeg"))
```

Comment: cv2.resize give error and error is "OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3718: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'"

Comment: Check your path. You are not reading image properly. Its None. Check the value of cv2.imread(). It should be None.

Comment: image is read properly. Error occurs where program comes at 2nd last line.

Comment: check your image size. `IMAGE_SIZE` should not be greater than original image size.

Comment: its work but resultant image is white no content is shown in image

Comment: Is there any other function which we can use in the replacement of cv2.resize?

Comment: now after changing saturation colors of image changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197431/discussion-between-waqas-ahmad-and-anubhav-singh).